# Deploy IPad application with its database

Tags: database, ios, ipad

can any one tell me if I could deploy an IPad application with its pre-initialized database?

I'm using IOS developer Enterprise program account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the database as a resource in the bundle and clone it into the users document folder at launch.

The reason to clone is that you dont get write privileges on bundle resources.

Alternatively since this is not code you could download it from the corporate server at launch but since you are asking this question you probably dont want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

You can use sqlite in your ios application. You can create locally an prefilled sqlite database, and at this one to your xcode project.

In your project you must copy the sqlitedatabase from your resourcesfolder to the app's documents folder.

Comment: thank you AltinkOnline, your answer is also correct but Stackoverflow dont allow me mark correct two times

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who's the developer of the app. If it's you, you can easily do so. Else, you won't be able (since apps are stored in a security sandbox).

If you really need to, you could consider jailbreaking them (you won't need a Enterprise Program though) so you can enter those sandboxes and add custom property lists to them.

Comment: Thank's for your feedback but I should not jailbreak the IPad, this application will be distributed later for many IPad, we are using Entreprise Program because we are developing this application for one of our customers wich is a company

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure you're developing the App yourself. For example, if you would want to install Things (or some other app) to all your employee's devices, that wouldn't be possible. (so my answer is mostly off-topic I think :P)